# How to screenshot only the area inside an Ellipse?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, screenshot

I'm creating a little snipping tool-like program in VB.NET and I can screenshot any area I want provided it is a rectangle area. I select the area in the screen and save it as an image. That's easy.

My problem is that I want to be able to screenshot not only a rectangular (standard rectangle shape area), but selecting/drawing an ellipse and screenshot the inside part of it. See the image below:

[image: screenshot only the inside of the Ellipse. the rest can be transparent]

is there any way to achieve this or any library I can use for that?

**Here's my current code:**

```
Public Class Form3
    Private _bRubberBandingOn As Boolean = False 
    Private _pClickStart As New Point 
    Private _pClickStop As New Point 
    Private _pNow As New Point 

    Private Sub Form3_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        Me._bRubberBandingOn = Not _bRubberBandingOn

        If Me._bRubberBandingOn Then
            If _pClickStart = Nothing Then _pClickStart = New Point
            _pClickStart.X = e.X
            _pClickStart.Y = e.Y
            _pNow.X = e.X
            _pNow.Y = e.Y
        End If
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

        If Me._bRubberBandingOn Then
            If _pNow = Nothing Then _pNow = New Point
            Me._pNow.X = e.X
            Me._pNow.Y = e.Y
            Me.Invalidate()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp

        Me._bRubberBandingOn = Not Me._bRubberBandingOn
        If Not Me._bRubberBandingOn Then
            If _pClickStop = Nothing Then _pClickStop = New Point
            _pClickStop.X = e.X
            _pClickStop.Y = e.Y
            Me.Invalidate()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim _rRectangle As New Rectangle
        Dim _penNew As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)

        _rRectangle.X = _pClickStart.X
        _rRectangle.Y = _pClickStart.Y

        If Me._bRubberBandingOn Then
            _rRectangle.Width = Me._pNow.X - _pClickStart.X
            _rRectangle.Height = Me._pNow.Y - _pClickStart.Y
        Else 
            _rRectangle.Width = Me._pClickStop.X - _pClickStart.X
            _rRectangle.Height = Me._pClickStop.Y - _pClickStart.Y

        End If
        _penNew.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(_penNew, _rRectangle)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Is there any way to achieve this or any library I can use for that?
Is it any way to get a handle of that painted line/shape and then use it to create a screenshot? I actually searched about this but didn't found anything meaningful yet.
thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Take the image that you are drawing the ellipse on top of and do the following:

```
Dim theBitmap As Bitmap = DirectCast(Image.FromFile("PathToFileYouAreDrawingEllipseOn.bmp"), Bitmap)
Dim theEllipseBitmap As New Bitmap(theBitmap.Width, theBitmap.Height)
Dim theGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(theEllipseBitmap)
Dim theGraphicsPath As New GraphicsPath()

' The (10,10) coordinates here are made up, you will need to take what is drawn by the user (starting x,y; ending x,y, etc.)
theGraphicsPath.AddEllipse(10, 10, theBitmap.Width - 20, theBitmap.Height - 20)
theGraphics.Clear(Color.Magenta)
theGraphics.SetClip(theGraphicsPath)
theGraphics.DrawImage(theBitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, theBitmap.Width, theBitmap.Height), 0, 0, theBitmap.Width, theBitmap.Height, _
GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
theGraphics.Dispose()
theEllipseBitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Magenta)

' Save the ellipse bitmap to a PNG file format
string fileName = "PathToYourDesiredOutput.png"
theEllipseBitmap.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```